# BOOST_MESSAGE undefined

Tags: c++, boost, quantlib

I have installed boost_1_54 on windows by checkout from svn and then

```
bootstrap
.\b2
```

QuantLib library dependent on boost compiles well all but one project: test-suite which uses BOOST_MESSAGE. this is undefined. I can see that there is no BOOST_MESSAGE in my version of boost.
Therefore is this QuantLib incompatibility or have I missed something? 
On my linux boost version the same thing applies to BOOST_MESSAGE - it is undefined

I have seen [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_0/libs/test/doc/components/test_tools/reference/deprecated.html) but I am not sure how to interpret this.

Comment: Do you know how deprecation works? It tells you: "Okay, we decided this way was bad and it's not really part of this library anymore. However, because we're nice we let you transition to the new stuff over a few releases, then it'll be gone for good." This is what happened to `BOOST_MESSAGE`. You might get away with a `#define BOOST_MESSAGE(msg) BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE(msg)` before including the QuantLib headers, though.

Comment: thank you, but do you really think a brand new version of QuantLib downloaded via svn, which is built certainly everyday by it's developers has this bug and each user is forced do #define BOOST_MESSAGE(msg) BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE(msg) on it's own? It is possible though not sure, so better ask. I believe something else happend here

Comment: Well, I don't think they also build Boost from svn source, as that would put a huge limit on the users of the library. It's a bit of a stretch to assume that libraries always stay on top of their dependencies, to be honest.

Comment: this question is marked quantlib, because it is quantlib related, I am not sure if you explained deprecation to assure yourself or for other reasons but this question is rather for users of quantlib, not for those who "think" how it works

Comment: And how does quantlib matter in any way to how Boost deprecates its stuff?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm afraid you gave us more credit than we deserved :)

We haven't compiled QuantLib against Boost svn yet.  The latest I've tried is Boost 1.53 (the latest released version) in which BOOST_MESSAGE was still available.

Thanks for the heads-up, though. I'll patch the library so that it's ready for next version. As mentioned in the comments, it should be as simple as adding

```
#if BOOST_VERSION > 105300
#define BOOST_MESSAGE(msg) BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE(msg)
#endif
```

to test-suite/utilities.hpp.

Comment: Hi Luigi,
thanks for the answer, I have posted to quantlib-dev list too.
BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE is undefined too, but I am still searching

Comment: and there are more things: BOOST_ERROR, BOOST_CHECK, also ambiguities regarding const void*=&boost::test_tools::check_is_close

Comment: I see. For the time being, I suggest sticking with Boost 1.53.

Answer (score 0):

on linux I had to add

> libboost_unit_test_framework.so

to the Linker->Libraries and

```
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

#define BOOST_MESSAGE( M )                  BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE( M )
```

is already present in test/test_tools.hpp.
on windows I have different #defines and this is not present, so I added it to the

> unit_test_log.hpp

where BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE is defined (in boost files to avoid same issue again in the case of other applications using BOOST_MESSAGE).
BOOST_MESSAGE issue resolved but still can't disambiguate

```
const void* = boost::test_tools::check_is_close
```

and

```
const void* = boost::test_tools::check_is_small
```

because these are templates. so the solution is to remove it (test-suite compiles well) or use appropriate pointers to function templates

Answer (score 0):

on Windows, after romoval or function

> _use_check

in utilities.hpp

changed to not have pointers to TEMPLATE functions as default, so changed to:

```
void _use_check(
                        const void*,
                        const void*) const {}
```

there were still errors while building test-suite project. unresolved externals: fdmhestonfwdop, fdmblackscholesfwdop, fdmsquarerootfwdop. obviously this classes (headers+source) I had to add to Quantlib project, build library QuantLib-vc110-mt-gd.lib again and rebuild test-suite project then. 
after pleasure with VS linker error "lnk1210 exceeded internal ilk size limit link with incremental no" (it really likes RAM, but on windows I have this resource quite limited), it is OK. compiled. : p